# Why is a floating title bar displaying on top of everything in my flutter app when I have no app bar in my scaffold?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-studio

Not sure when it occurred but a few days after making pushes to my app's code, a weird gray bar popped up on the top of the emulator with the title of my app.

This is not an app bar - I know because even if I add an app bar to my scaffold purposefully, it will add one under this bizzare bar.

This is what the bar looks like on different screens:

[Image of the weird bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TSXl.png)

[The bar on a different page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZHv0.png)

It says the name of the app "anywaypay." On the second image, it shows a page that is wrapped in a safe view. It seems that this bar is outside of the safeview and pushes everything in the safeview down. Note that the first page does not have a safeview which is why it is not pushed down below the bar.

If it helps - the problem does not happen on the IOS emulator.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

I have tried reverting Github changes but nothing seems to get rid of it.

I have tried different emulators... they all have the bar.

Comment: Hi Grind Clock, welcome to the stackoverflow. Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `styles.xml` and change theme to `<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">`